# Php exec() with get or post

Tags: php, exec

Hi i have this problem

1. i make ajax post to file insert.php
2. i make exec() on insert.php to send.php

I need pass with POST or GET data using exec() from insert.php to send.php

Here ist my code but ist not pass nothing

```
$data = array(
    'user' => '1001',
    'area' => 'any',
    'type' => 'any',
    'max' => '100'
  );
  $query = http_build_query($data);
  shell_exec("php " . ROOT . "/send.php  " . $query . " &> /dev/null &");
```

On send.php i simple email for reciving info print_r($_REQUEST); but i just recive helloArray
()

Please Help with any solution

With help of @barmar

```
$data = array(
    'user' => '1001',
    'area' => 'any',
    'type' => 'any',
    'max' => '100'
  );
  $query = escapeshellarg(http_build_query($data));
  exec("php " . ROOT . "/mail.php  " . $query . " &> /dev/null &");
```

on send.php

```
 parse_str($argv[1], $data);
    $data['user'];
    $data['area'];
    $data['type'];
    $data['max'];
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST` can only be used in scripts invoked from the webserver. You're invoking `send.php` from CLI, not webserver, so it doesn't get any `$_REQUEST` parameters.

Comment: It seems like you should be using `include()`, not `shell_exec()`.

Comment: @Barmar $_REQUEST it not problem  i not get ant parametar user, area .. and i know that i can use include but i need to do backgroun proces on send,php

Comment: Why are you not just using `require()` to run the PHP directly?

Comment: @miken32 i need run 0 - 1k notification  so i canot use require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `$query`, since it will probably contain some characters that have special meaning to the shell.

```
$query = escapeshellarg(http_build_query($data));
```

In `send.php`, use `$argv[1]` to get the value of `$query`. You can use [`parse_str($argv[1], $data)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to extract the parameter values from it into the `$data` array, then you can use `$data['area']` to get that parameter.

Comment: i ad escape but i dont understant what about parse_str() how to use it on send.php  i schould get $_GET['area'], ....

Comment: this schould be passed 'user=1001&area=any&type=any&max=100' but i not get any response on send.php

Comment: After `parse_str()` you can use `$data['area']`

Comment: yes that i understand but what string i schould parse on send.php  parse_str(???, $data)  whitch string i need parse ???